# Get data from either one of two select input with the same name attribute

Tags: javascript, php, input, drop-down-menu, radio-button

I try to develop an **update/edit form** that have a set of **radio button** and also **two different drop down list**.

**HTML**

2 Radio Button - Populated from SQL Database (One & Two) :

```
<?php if ($rows_item['choice'] == "One" )  {?><input name="owner_c" id="owner_c1" type="radio" value="One" checked="checked" onclick="show1()"/>One<?php } ?>
<?php if ($rows_item['choice'] == "Two" )  {?><input name="owner_c" id="owner_c2" type="radio" value="Two" checked="checked" onclick="show2()"/>Two<?php } ?>
```

2 Drop Down List - Populated from SQL Database by while loop (Section & Department) :

```
<div id="div1" class="<?php if ($rows_item['choice'] != "One") { echo "hide";} ?>">
<p align="center">
  <?php
  if ($rows_item['choice'] == "One") {
      $sql_section = "SELECT * FROM borrower_section";
      $query_section = mysql_query($sql_section) or die('Error:'.mysql_error());
      ?>
  <select name="dept" id="dept1" style="width:400px;" required >
    <option value="-1" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Sections *</option>
    <?php while ($row_section = mysql_fetch_array($query_section)) { ?>
    <option <?php if($rows_item['dept']==$row_section['sections']) { echo "selected";} ?> value="<?php echo $row_section['sections']; ?>"><?php echo $row_section['sections']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
</p>
</div>


<div id="div2" class="<?php if ($rows_item['choice'] != "Two") { echo "hide";} ?>">
<p align="center">
  <?php
  }
  if ($rows_item['choice'] == "Two") {
      $sql_dept = "SELECT * FROM borrower_dept";
      $query_dept = mysql_query($sql_dept) or die('Error:'.mysql_error());
      ?>
  <select name="dept" id="dept2" style="width:400px;" >
    <option value="-1" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Departments *</option>
    <?php while ($row_dept = mysql_fetch_array($query_dept)) { ?>
    <option <?php if($rows_item['dept']==$row_dept['dept_name']) { echo "selected";} ?> value="<?php echo $row_dept['dept_name']; ?>"><?php echo $row_dept['dept_name']; ?></option>
    <?php }}?>
  </select>
</p>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function show1(){
document.getElementById('div1').style.display ='block'; 
document.getElementById('div2').style.display ='none'; 
$('#dept2').removeAttr('required');
$('#dept1').attr('required','required');
}

function show2(){
document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';
$('#dept1').removeAttr('required');
$('#dept2').attr('required','required');
}
```

The flow is; if user choose **radio button One**, **"div1" will appear - "div2" is hidden** and user will select any items and save in database through **input name=dept**.

And if user choose **radio button Two**, **"div2" will appear - "div1" is hidden** and user will select any items in it and **also save in database through input name=dept**.

My problem is, if user choose radio button One, they **have to submit this form twice** in order to save the record for "dept" in SQL database. Both **drop down list is using the same name** because I want to **fetch data from either one and save in the same column=dept in SQL based on which radio button they choose**.

How to prevent this and allow user to submit one time?
TQ..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could try naming the inputs **dept[1]** and **dept[2]** and then simply set $_POST['dept'] to contain the one that's been filled.

The inputs:

```
<select name="dept[1]" id="dept1" style="width:400px;" required >...</select>
<select name="dept[2]" id="dept1" style="width:400px;" required >...</select>
```

The php:

```
$_POST['dept'] = !empty($_POST['dept'][1]) ? $_POST['dept'][1] : $_POST['dept'][2];
```

And then you can simply continue as you would if you "filtered" the input with javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I didn't know that we could store input in array "dept[1]". I think the reason why this form need to submit twice is; php can't read which input to fetch.

Comment: I've tried to put that code; but that only work with the first drop down menu, I still have to submit twice for second drop down menu/

Comment: @Alieym are both inputs visible? If you set an input to display: none; it doesn't get submitted. So you can either have both somehow visible and use the PHP I gave you to get the right value, or have one hidden with javascript and use the one that's visible. In that case I suggest you add a secondary input with type="hidden" that will hold the index as its value. I'm not sure if my description is clear enough, so feel free to ask if you don't understand what I mean.

Comment: in my code, i use 2 way to hide another dropdown list.. **(1) CSS** using class = "hide"; display:none; **(2) Javascript** document.getElementById('div2').style.display ='none'; Which one will effect my form submission?

Comment: I am not really sure, after doing some research it seems that it might depend on the browser. The best way to disable an element is to set it to display: none and setting the disabled attribute. I will try to write a better example using these, however I need to know one thing first - does your application have access to jquery?